# ConstraintLayout и Dialog

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть вот такой макет:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге получается вот это:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно заметить, диалог обрезает кнопку. Никак не могу решить проблему с условием, что второй `EditText` больше первого и кнопка имеет определенный размер в `dpi`.

Разметка:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newCategory_titleTV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/new_dialog_title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Title"
        android:textColor="@color/material_drawer_dark_primary_text"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newCategory_btnLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newCategory_category_textInputLayout">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newCategory_negativeBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dialog_negative_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newCategory_positiveBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dialog_positive_btn" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/newCategory_money_textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/myTextInputLayoutHint"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline11"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newCategory_titleTV">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/newCategory_moneyET"
            style="@style/myAppCompatLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
            android:hint="@string/newCategory_dialog_sum_num_hint"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLength="7"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="8dp" />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline10"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.82" />

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.35" />

    <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
        android:id="@+id/newCategory_colorBtn"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/newCategory_category_textInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newCategory_titleTV"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
        fancy:fb_borderColor="@color/colorAccent"
        fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
        fancy:fb_defaultColor="@color/colorPrimary"
        fancy:fb_focusColor="@color/colorFocusColor"
        fancy:fb_radius="50dp"
        fancy:fb_text="" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/newCategory_category_textInputLayout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@style/myTextInputLayoutHint"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/newCategory_money_textInputLayout"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline10"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/newCategory_titleTV">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/newCategory_categoryET"
            style="@style/myAppCompatLarge"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
            android:hint="@string/newCategory_dialog_category_hint"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"
            android:maxLength="15"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:padding="8dp" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**UPD.** Разметка построенная на LinearLayout.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fancy="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/newCategory_titleTV"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/new_dialog_title"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Light.SearchResult.Title"
        android:textColor="@color/material_drawer_dark_primary_text"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newCategory_dataLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/newCategory_money_textInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="60"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/myTextInputLayoutHint">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/newCategory_moneyET"
                style="@style/myAppCompatLarge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                android:hint="@string/newCategory_dialog_sum_num_hint"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:maxLength="7"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="8dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/newCategory_category_textInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_weight="45"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/myTextInputLayoutHint">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/newCategory_categoryET"
                style="@style/myAppCompatLarge"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/edittext_background"
                android:hint="@string/newCategory_dialog_category_hint"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"
                android:maxLength="15"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:padding="8dp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <mehdi.sakout.fancybuttons.FancyButton
            android:id="@+id/newCategory_colorBtn"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            fancy:fb_borderColor="@color/colorAccent"
            fancy:fb_borderWidth="1dp"
            fancy:fb_defaultColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            fancy:fb_focusColor="@color/colorFocusColor"
            fancy:fb_radius="50dp"
            fancy:fb_text="" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/newCategory_btnLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newCategory_negativeBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dialog_negative_btn" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/newCategory_positiveBtn"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="@string/dialog_positive_btn" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Покажите разметку. Скорее всего вам не нужен тут `ConstraintLayout` и всё это проще сделать обычными спосбами

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, Добавил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPD** Чтобы установить размер диалогу, в котором виджетам нельзя установить размер на весь экран диалога (как `EditText`) нужно создать новый стиль, где указываем процентное отношение от всего экрана в портретном (в примере 90%) и альбомном (в примере 70%) режиме:

*res/styles.xml*:

```
<style name="DialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">70%</item>
    <item name="android:windowMinWidthMinor">90%</item>
</style>
```

атрибуты доступны с библиотеки поддержки *AppCompat* версии 22.2.0

В начале, что у меня получилось:

[image: scr]

код *DialogFragment.java* (устанавливаем стиль для диалога):

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment  {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_dialog, container, false);
    }

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, R.style.DialogStyle);
   }
}
```

разметка *fragment_dialog.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:text="Новая запись"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="сумма"
        android:labelFor="@+id/edit1"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="2"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionNext"
            android:inputType="numberDecimal" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/editText2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:hint="название"
        android:labelFor="@+id/edit2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight="3"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/editText1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/edit2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:imeOptions="actionDone"
            android:inputType="text" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:src="@android:drawable/presence_online"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/editText2"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/editText2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="ок"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:text="отмена"
        app:layout_constraintBaseline_toBaselineOf="@+id/button1"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/button1" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Двум `EditText` указывается максимальный размер, затем они сввязываются в цепочку и им устанавливается вес через атрибут `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_weight`.
Кнопки прижаты к правому краю в соответствии с последними гайдлайнами.
Фокус перенесен на корневой layout через атрибут `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`, чтобы первое поле ввода не было "раскрыто" при открытии диалога, а выглядело как на скриншоте. Если такое поведение не надо, данный атрибут нужно убрать, тогда диалог будет открываться, как на первом скриншоте в вопросе (фокус на первом поле `EditText`).
Поля ввода имеют атрибуты для числового ввода, переключения на следующее поле ввода с клавиатуры (Next) и защита от перевода строки (Done)

Comment: Мне помогло немного другое решение. Как я в комментах уже говорил, устанавливая ширину программно, получаем в `Landscape` некрасивый диалог. Я сделал всё через `LinearLayout` как говорил @ЮрийСпб, а для того, чтобы выглядели нормально в `EditText`ы установил `MinWidth`, причем неважно поставить там 100dp или 250dp, диалог (не знаю как) устанавливает ширину относительную, т.е. поставив 40 `EditText` будет короткий в любой ориентации и на любых устройствах (хотя отличаться должны, хоть это `dpi`), если 1000, то он будет ставить максимально допустимую.

Comment: Чуть не забыл, устанавливал `minWidth` не для `EditText`, а для `TextInputLayout` в каждом из которых `EditText`.

Comment: @Ivan звучит как то костыльно :). В принципе ConstrainLayout позволяет сверстать все в одном контейнере с лучшим масштабированием на разных экранах, но дело, конечно, ваше. и minWidth не надо устанавливать, у меня чувство, что оно может подвести

Comment: а за `<item name="android:windowMinWidthMajor">70%</item>` отдельное спасибо, не мог найти.

Answer (score 1):

Тут не нужен `ConstraintLayout`, в т.ч. потому что диалоги немного по другому разметку загруженную отображают из-за меньшей ширины чем экран.

Можно сделать как-то так (псевдо разметка):

```
<Linear vertical>

    <TextView title>

    <Linear horizontal>

        <EditText weight=40> <EditText weight=60> <Circle width=40dp>

    </Linear horizontal>

    <Linear horizontal>

        <Button weight=1> <Button weight=1>

    </Linear horizontal>

</Linear vertical>
```

Comment: Я пробовал уже тело диалога (без заголовка и кнопок) запихать в Linear, но он вообще ничего не показывал(как будто прозрачный диалог), либо как он любит, диалог шириной в пару сантиметров, где у `EditText` была ширина в 1 символ. Еще пробовал программно расширить диалог до максимума, но при повороте получается франкенштейн.

Comment: Тут главная проблема в том как корректно установить ширину, чтобы `EditText` был и ни маленьким (в 1 символ) и не здоровым (за экран уходящий) и при этом вмещалась кнопка.

Comment: Повторил как вы описали, вот что вышло (добавил скрин)

Comment: @Ivan, попробуйте тогда программно установить ширину так: `dialog.getWindow().setLayout(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);`

Comment: @Ivan, лично я вот эту либу для диалогов юзаю и там, вроде, нет таких проблем: https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs

Comment: @pavlofff в этом то и проблема, что именно такой макет не могу "приготовить", вчера по вашему методу сделал другой диалог и всё шикарно. Единственное, что более менее помогло здесь это построить весь макет как сказал @ЮрийСПб,  и установить `minWidth`, но мне кажется, что это как собрать автомобиль, но из дерева.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб именно так я и ставил ширину но при повороте экрана он занимал всю область, что выглядело ужасно.